# How to change date format in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change date format from 2018-03-23 to DD-MM-YYYY.

Here is my input XML file:

```
<ClientList>
   <Client>
     <CreateDate>2018-03-23</CreateDate>
   </Client>
</ClientList>
```

Here is my XSL file which just shown date like in input XML.

```
<ClientList>
  <Client>
    <Data>
    <xsl:value-of select="CreateDate"/>
    </Data>
  </Client>
</ClientList>
```

How can I change the date format to DD-MM-YYYY (23-03-2018)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(CreateDate, '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]')"/>
```

If you are only using XSLT 1.0 then do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(CreateDate, 9, 2), '-', substring(CreateDate, 6, 2), '-', substring(CreateDate, 1, 4))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:template match="ClientList">
        <xsl:element name="ClientList">
            <xsl:for-each select="Client">
            <xsl:element name="Client">
                <xsl:element name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(CreateDate,'[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```